# finder roo fails

Tags: spring-roo

I have a simple roo, postgres application.

I generated my finders, they are generated and they appear on the browser.

But not matter what argument I type in the search, I am redirected to the "List All" page and the search always returns me the list of ALL rows in the table.
What could be the problem ?

Comment: Some code of would help.

Comment: finder add findGotsByNafnIsNull , all generated finders invariably returns the all list of row on my entity.

Comment: Snippet of generated code. How does Gots_Roo_Finder.aj looks? Does Nafn is set(not null)?

Comment: I took another field as the example. My finder has been generated findGotsByDnaIsNotNull. Got finder look like :public static TypedQuery<Got> Got.findGotsByDnaIsNotNull() {
        EntityManager em = Got.entityManager();
        TypedQuery<Got> q = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Got AS o WHERE o.Dna IS NOT NULL", Got.class);
        return q;
    }

Comment: I have noticed during debbugging that when launching the finder, the resquest is directed to the action public static List<Got> findAllGotsUser() {} and not towards the  Got.findGotsByDnaIsNotNull()

Comment: When I click on the button of the finder form. The request is redirected to the List function in the GotController.java and not towards the finder why ?

Comment: Do you have appropriate method in GoController_Roo_.aj? What is link in menu.jspx file?

Comment: What method should be in the GotController_Roo_Controller.aj ? I have the method findGotsByDnaIsNotNullForm in my GotController_Roo_Controller_Finder.aj. But in this method I can just see: return "gots/findGotsByDnaIsNotNull";                  The link in the menu is : url="/gots?find=ByDnaIsNotNull&amp;form"

Comment: If you create other finders does they work? Maybe it is related to [https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2032](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2032)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Roo are you using?

In version 1.1.3 there was a bug where Finders weren't being generated https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-2362

If you upgrade to version 1.1.4, roo will detect your finder annotations and create them properly.